# Is $\frac{1}{L(1+it)}$ unbounded?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, l-functions, dirichlet-series

Let $\chi$ be a Dirichlet character and $L(s, \chi)$ be the corresponding L-function. Is $$\frac{1}{L(1+it, \chi)}$$ unbounded for $t \in \mathbb{R}$? I'm aware that this is true if $L=\zeta$, but I'm not sure of general $L$.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is known to hold, and for more general families of $L$-functions. See in particular Theorem 3.1 and the discussion following it in "[Extremal values of Dirichlet $L$-functions in the half-plane of absolute convergence](https://doi.org/10.5802/jtnb.444)
" by Jörn Steuding.

Comment: I found no Theorem 0.8 in Lamzouri's paper (journal or arXiv).  Also, unless I'm missing something, Littlewood's result only bounds $|L(1+it,\chi)|$ and does not ensure the existence of $t$ such that $|L(1+it,\chi)|$ is small.

Comment: Apologies; I misunderstood and thought you were interested in large values, not small values. I'll give another reference.

Comment: Littlewood's idea still works, but you need some information about the value distribution of twisted characters. Example: Large values of $L(1,\chi)$ can be found along a sequence of $\chi$ with $\chi(p)=1$ for all $p\leq O(\log q_{\chi})$ (such $\chi$ exist via Pell equation arguments; see Montgomery and Weinberger https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01351721). When $\chi$ is fixed and $|t|$ is large, one must know something about the value distribution of $\chi(p)p^{-it}$ to ensure small (or large) values of $L(1+it,\chi)$. Plug this into Littlewood's truncated Euler product.